# can we avoid eloquent in large no of records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization

I am using laravel eloquent and have condition where thousands of records inside database so when using eloquent relationship my query is executing slow. Should i avoid using eloquent in these satuations or any other way?

here is mysql query

```
$leads=Lead::select($col)
                ->join("gc_od_leads_detail as ld", "gc_od_leads.leads_id", "=", "ld.ld_leads_id")
                ->join("gc_od_chat as c", "gc_od_leads.leads_chat_id", "=", "c.chat_id")
                ->join("gc_od_group as g", "c.chat_group_id", "=", "g.group_octachat_id")
                ->where('c.chat_tags','sales')
                ->whereIn('c.chat_group_id',$filter['groups']);
            if(!empty($filter['keyword'])) {
                $leads=$leads->where(function ($q) use ($filter) {
                           $q->where('ld_name','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%")
                           ->orWhere('ld_email','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%")
                           ->orWhere('ld_phoneno','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%");
                   });
            }
            if(!empty($filter['startDate']) && !empty($filter['endDate'])){
                $leads=$leads->whereBetween('leads_created_date', [$filter['startDate']." 00:00:00",$filter['endDate']." 23:59:59"]);
            }
            $leads=$leads->orderBy('leads_created_date','desc');
            return $leads;
        }
```

I have more than 500 000 recordings in side messages and chats table. i changed query in eloquent and debugged it

Query:

```
    Lead::select('leads_id','leads_chat_id')->with(["detail"=>function($q){
               $q->select("ld_leads_id");
           }])->with(["chat"=>function($q){
               $q->select("chat_id")->where(['chat_status'=>1]);
           }])->where("leads_status",1)->get();

Debuging Ouput
    array:3 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select `leads_id`, `leads_chat_id` from `gc_od_leads` where `leads_status` = ?"
        "bindings" => array:1 [▼
          0 => 1
        ]
        "time" => 14.85
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select `ld_leads_id` from `gc_od_leads_detail` where `gc_od_leads_detail`.`ld_leads_id` in (2278918, 2278919, 2278920, 2278921, 2278922, 2278923, 2278924, 22789 ▶"
        "bindings" => []
        "time" => 0.59
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select `chat_id` from `gc_od_chat` where `gc_od_chat`.`chat_id` in (3496457, 3496458, 3496459, 3496460, 3496461, 3496462, 3496463, 3496464, 3496465, 3496466, 34 ▶"
        "bindings" => array:1 [▶]
        "time" => 4.21
      ]
    ]
```

i above output you can see that it get all records of leads first then going to lead detail and chats table if i only want to find out the leads having chat status =1 it will still query all leads this is what slowing my query

where we use join it will not work in this way i think which will save time and space both that's my i post this question i think a lot of people having same problem and no one discuss this point

Comment: _"should i avoid using eloquent in these satuations"_ - Have you tried without Eloquent to see if there even is a difference? You need to debug/profile your code/queries to find out where the slow down comes from before deciding on the final solution. Have you added proper indexes to your tables? And how many records are "thousands" exactly?

Comment: yes I debug queries and found that there was inner queries due to where clauses which was making execution slower

Comment: Please add _all_ information to your question. If you've done debugging/profiling etc, we need to know that. You're basically asking us what you should do while having much more information than us.

Comment: ok i will, but tell me one thing can you convert above defined query in eloquent way don't you think i will take more time  if having large no of records ??

Comment: There's nothing inherently ineffecient about how Eloquent turns the code you give it into SQL queries. You certainly may switch to using native SQL if you wish. It's slightly easier to read for people helping you with performance.

Comment: It's impossible to know if it takes longer or not unless you test/time both ways and compare them. As far as we know, eloquent might generate an identical query as the one you would write yourself, then the "overhead" of using eloquent would be too small to notice.

Comment: ok let me update my question

Comment: I honestly don't think this is a good question since you already have all the tools to test this yourself (which we don't). We simply can't make this determination for you.

Comment: If you want help optimizing your query please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and then [edit] your question to show us your index and table definitions. Query optimization is usually a matter of adding, and maybe removing, indexes.

Comment: on you request i debug query and explain more about my issue please check it thanks

Comment: @O.Jones please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at one part of this.

```php
if(!empty($filter['keyword'])) {
   $leads=$leads->where(function ($q) use ($filter) {
          $q->where('ld_name','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%")
            ->orWhere('ld_email','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%")
            ->orWhere('ld_phoneno','like', "%".$filter['keyword']."%");
       });
 }
```

This keyword-matching scheme is inherently, and disastrously, slow. It's slow in both Eloquent and native SQL.  There's no way it can work in MySQL without doing a [full table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html). That is, it must examine every row of your table looking for matches and cannot, in MySQL, exploit any indexed lookup scheme. Why?

```
column LIKE 'constant%'
```

can look at an index on `column` and quickly find any value starting with `'constant'`. But

```
column LIKE '%constant%'
```

has to look at every value in the table. The leading `%` makes the index lookup useless.

In MySQL you would be wise to investigate [MySQL's FULLTEXT searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) as a way of handling your keyword lookup.  (Recent versions of postgreSQL can handle this sort of query directly with a different kind of index, but not MySQL.)

Comment: i edited the question please check it thanks