# Laravel Eloquent Making Query Execution Slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

i am using laravel eloquent relationships and having slow query execution issue
let say i have two table
chats(**1 Million Records**)
leads(**half Million Records**)
and i want to query chats & lead data of a group where using

```
 lead::select("chat_lead_id")->with([chats=>function($q){
    $q->select('chat_id',"group_id")->where("group_id"=>1)
    })
```

Query Debug
First Query :

```
result =select chat_lead_id from leads
```

Second Query

```
select chat_id,group_id from chats  where group_id =1 AND chat_id in (result)
```

please check above debug you can see that First Query will fetch **half million rows from database** which will take to much time
so what should i do move to join query ??
when using WhereHas it is placing inner query which is taking time also
**Query With WhereHas**

```
select * from `gc_od_leads`
    where exists (select * from `gc_od_chat`
            where `gc_od_leads`.`leads_chat_id`
                = `gc_od_chat`.`chat_id`
              and `chat_group_id` = ?)
```

Comment: You're looking for the `whereHas` method.

Comment: whereHas is doing inner query which is making more slow

Comment: You may need to add an index for group_id and chat_id. The other option is to do a left join instead of a subquery, which will reduce the number of queries.

Comment: please check my updated question with wherehas query you means i need to move on joins instead of relationships

Answer (score 0):

since you have half million rows, I think you should just [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) your tables:

```
 $values=lead::query()->join('chats','leads.chat_lead_id','=','chats.chat_id')
            ->where("group_id",=,1)->select(["chat_lead_id",'chat_id',"group_id"])->get();
```

Comment: i am using join i just want to confirm that using join is the only solution and no solution in eloquent for these case right ??

Comment: i post this question and people start saying me wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815015/can-we-avoid-eloquent-in-large-no-of-records?noredirect=1#comment118108194_66815015 here

Comment: join is fastest way to make this query, other way is far more slower

Answer (score 0):

```
where group_id =1 AND chat_id in (result)
```

needs this composite index:  `INDEX(group_id, chat_id)`